# Не знаю как достать данные из XML файла

Tags: c#, xml

Все статьи на эту тему у меня не выходят. Я уверен что я делаю что-то не правильно, но не понимаю что.
Ситуация:

Есть модель чтения данных

```
    class ItemModel
    {
        public ItemModel(string name, int weight, int sg, int volume)
        {
            Name = name;
            Weight = weight;
            Sg = sg;
            Volume = volume; 
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public int Sg { get; set; }
        public int Volume { get; set; }
    }
```

Есть модель которая скармливает данные

```
public List<ItemModel> GetItems() =>
        new List<ItemModel>
        {
            new ItemModel("Water", 0, 1, 0),
            new ItemModel("Ballast", 0, 1, 0),
            new ItemModel("Oil", 0, 1, 0),
        };
```

А есть XML файл

```
<ballast>
  <tank ID="FPTW" Name="Forepeak" Weight="0,00" SG="1,025" Volume="0,00">
    <volume x="52.00" y="-0.90" z="0.00">0.00</volume>
    <volume x="53.48" y="0.00" z="0.05">0.77</volume>
    <volume x="53,70" y="0,00" z="0,11">1,99</volume>
```

Вопрос: Как мне собственно достать данные из Файла?

```
public class XMLModel
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(XMLFile1.xml);
}
```

у меня даже на старте ошибку выдаёт

Comment: И сразу вопрос с очевидным ответом, но не для меня - для типа double должны быть точки или запятые?

Comment: Разделитель зависит от культуры, хотя xml не должен зависеть от нее, поэтому там должна использоваться только точки

Comment: Ну и непонятно какая связь между приведенным кодом и xml. Почитайте про xml-сериализацию

Comment: А где код, где вы что-то пытаетесь считать из XML?

Comment: связи никакой, я и спрашиваю как её сделать. То есть заменить класс который вливает данные на класс который читает xml и вливает его данные

Comment: XDocument.Parse -это ваша отправная точка. Дальше, циклами перебираете. Альтернативное решение-это сериализация.

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил в вопрос класс. В чём ошибка не пойму

Comment: @LeeShane и что именно у вас не получается? 1) Синтаксически класс неверен.2)Вы просто читаете данные, а где вы с ними работаете? Где сама проблема?

Comment: проблема в том, что даже doc VS не воспринимает. "имя doc не существует в текущем контексте"

Comment: В каком смысле не воспринимает? Сейчас ваш класс синтаксически неверный, так как не может так просто вызывать метод поля находясь нигде. Поместить его например в метод.